# WCF Connected SOAP Service xml Deserialization Issue of .net Generated Classes same parent child name

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, .net-6.0

I Am facing an issue, i connected to a WCF service in my .net 6 web API.

the Expected xml to be deserialized into class is below

```
<AttributeGroups>
                  <DisplayName>Product Document</DisplayName>
                  <Key>132747.7</Key>
                  <Type>Category</Type>
                  <Values xsi:type="q19:StringValue" xmlns:q19="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com">
                     <q19:Description>Document Id</q19:Description>
                     <q19:Key>132747.7.30</q19:Key>
                     <q19:Values>SAMPLE_ID THAT I AM NOT GETTING</q19:Values>
                  </Values>
                  <Values xsi:type="q20:StringValue" xmlns:q20="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com">
                     <q20:Description>Document Part Id</q20:Description>
                     <q20:Key>132747.7.7</q20:Key>
                  </Values>
                  <Values xsi:type="q21:StringValue" xmlns:q21="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com">
                     <q21:Description>Language Code</q21:Description>
                     <q21:Key>132747.7.50</q21:Key>
                     <q21:Values>de</q21:Values> // also NOT ABLE TO GET
                  </Values>
</AttributeGroups>
```

The Class structure that .net generated is as below:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DataValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PrimitiveValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(IntegerValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DateValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BooleanValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RealValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(StringValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RowValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(TableValue))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="ServiceDataObject", Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public abstract partial class ServiceDataObject1
    {
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PrimitiveValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(IntegerValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DateValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BooleanValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RealValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(StringValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RowValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(TableValue))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class DataValue : ServiceDataObject1
    {
        
        private string descriptionField;
        
        private string keyField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return this.descriptionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.descriptionField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(IntegerValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DateValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BooleanValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RealValue))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(StringValue))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class PrimitiveValue : DataValue
    {
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class IntegerValue : PrimitiveValue
    {
        
        private System.Nullable<long>[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
        public System.Nullable<long>[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class DateValue : PrimitiveValue
    {
        
        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime>[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime>[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class BooleanValue : PrimitiveValue
    {
        
        private System.Nullable<bool>[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
        public System.Nullable<bool>[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class RealValue : PrimitiveValue
    {
        
        private System.Nullable<double>[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
        public System.Nullable<double>[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class StringValue : PrimitiveValue
    {
        
        private string[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", Order=0)]
        public string[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class RowValue : DataValue
    {
        
        private DataValue[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", Order=0)]
        public DataValue[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:Core.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class TableValue : DataValue
    {
        
        private RowValue[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", Order=0)]
        public RowValue[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(AttributeGroup))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Metadata))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Version))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:DocMan.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public abstract partial class ServiceDataObject
    {
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:DocMan.service.livelink.opentext.com")]
    public partial class AttributeGroup : ServiceDataObject
    {
        
        private string displayNameField;
        
        private string keyField;
        
        private string typeField;
        
        private DataValue[] valuesField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.displayNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.displayNameField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", Order=3)]
        public DataValue[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valuesField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is my DataValue Class is missing Values due to which i am not able to get Document ID and Language Code.

If i try to define the DataValue Class as below:
public partial class DataValue : ServiceDataObject1
{

```
    private string descriptionField;

    private string keyField;

    private string valuesField;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values", IsNullable=true, Order=2)]
    public string Values
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valuesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valuesField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Member IntegerValue.Values of type System.Nullable`1[System.Int64][] hides base class member DataValue.Values of type System.String. Use XmlElementAttribute or XmlAttributeAttribute to specify a new name.

AnyIdea , what can help here, FYI i tried adding new Value where ever possible in PrimitiveValue Child Classes, still doesn't work.

Comment: The xml contains 'type' attributes which means there is a base class and inherited classes.  So you must add the inherited classes and use the attribute [XmlInclude].  See following for an example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=net-7.0&force_isolation=true

Comment: As the log says, you may use XmlElementAttribute) or [XmlAttributeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=net-7.0) to specify a new name.

Comment: Hi @jdweng , can you clarify a little more , i see [Xmlnclude] can be only used on methods, class and struct level not on properties  level. i would like to try your solution , can you provide me some more details

Comment: Hi @Jiayao i tried below , still doesn't work
```
[XmlElementAttribute(ElementName ="Values",DataType ="string",Order =2,IsNullable =true)]
        public string Value
       
```

it says System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetDocumentMetadata'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2037).
 ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Element' is an invalid XmlNodeType. Line 1, position 2037.

Comment: I tried but there isn't enough of the xml and classes to be able to duplicate your issue.